# DataSet returns error "Must declare the scalar variable ..."

Tags: sql, sql-server, dataset

I'm trying to add a query to my dataset and getting an error "Must declare the scalar variable @searchstr".  I find this a little odd because I've used the @variable to pass parameters before no problem, but for whatever reason it fails here.

```
select DISTINCT g.groupname, 
CASE WHEN s.siteguid = @searchstr THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS doesitexist
from groups g left outer join sitegroups as sg on g.groupguid = sg.groupguid 
left outer join sites as s on sg.siteguid = s.siteguid
```

Found it fails in LINQPad as well, so add a little more info, though sadly this still doesn't work in a DataSet.  :-(  The below works in LINQPad, and SQL Server Management Studio.

```
declare @searchstr nvarchar(64);
set @searchstr = '21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D';
select DISTINCT g.groupname, 
CASE WHEN s.siteguid = @searchstr THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS doesitexist
from groups g left outer join sitegroups as sg on g.groupguid = sg.groupguid 
left outer join sites as s on sg.siteguid = s.siteguid
```

What am I doing wrong that's tripping me up?  Suspect WHEN is tripping me up?

Comment: I'm not sure why it is giving you the error you mentioned, but I am curious why you declared `@searchstr` to be an `nvarchar(64)`. Is `siteguid` not typed as a `uniqueidentifier`?

Comment: Oh, I was just throwing some code together to see where my SQL was valid.  Seems to work fine, I was halve hoping to fudge it into my DataSet however you can't use DECLARE or SET in a DataSet query

Comment: I gave up and rewrote the query without using CASE or WHEN statements.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to try this to force the parser to get the parameter

```
select DISTINCT g.groupname, 
CASE WHEN s.siteguid = @searchstr THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS doesitexist
from groups g left outer join sitegroups as sg on g.groupguid = sg.groupguid 
left outer join sites as s on sg.siteguid = s.siteguid
WHERE (@searchstr = '' OR 1 = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's not incorrect in the sql, but at another location (Parameter definition, etc.)?

Comment: Something I've noticed is for the top example @searchstr should appear on the DataSet as a parameter, however it doesn't.  However when I add WHERE condition a parameter is created.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably confused because you're not using the parameter in the WHERE statement.  At a glance this doesn't look like something you should be doing at the SQL Server anyway as it doesn't affect the specific rows returned.

Maybe give a bit more info on what you actually want to achieve with this SQL?

Comment: It returns the first column and a BOOL value for the second of 0, or 1,  based on whether or not an entry exists.